# Relative URL in file not working after setting vhosts

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

This is my folder structure

```
+ Duplicate
    + Controllers
        - LoginController.php
    + Models
    + Views
        - Index.php
```

The contents of my http-vhosts.conf file is:

```
ServerName example.dev
ServerAlias www.example.dev
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Duplicate/Views/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/Duplicate/Views/">
```

My index file contains a header as such

```
header("Location: ../Controllers/LoginController.php");
```

The `LoginController` never gets loaded. This is what I understand of what's happening.

The URL *example.dev* always contains */Views/*, so even when I try to change the *Location* header to the parent folder, the path gets appended to my *example.dev* URL which again contains */Views/*.

What am I supposed to do for it to work. I've been stuck all day trying to get it to load the page.

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: Not using any framework right now because I want to get good with core php first.

Comment: try `header("Location: /Controllers/LoginController.php");` (without two dots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this setting you cannot access the LoginController.php, because it differs from the DocumentRoot.

```
DocumentRoot = C:/wamp/www/Duplicate/Views/
File         = C:/wamp/www/Duplicate/Controllers/LoginController.php
```

Direct access should only be possible for files, that are in the DocumentRoot (or any of its subfolders).

You maybe can change your DocumentRoot to "C:/wamp/www/Duplicate/" and put an index.php in that folder that redirects you to "Views/".